# how to push commit to an existing repo

Tags: bash, git

How to commit changes to an existing repo?

```
$ git remote -v

github  git@github.com:jhardik366/yelp-camp.git (fetch)

github  git@github.com:jhardik366/yelp-camp.git (push)

heroku  https://git.heroku.com/yelp-camp-19.git (fetch)

heroku  https://git.heroku.com/yelp-camp-19.git (push)

origin  git@github.com:jhardik366/c9.git (fetch)

origin  git@github.com:jhardik366/c9.git (push)
```

How to push to yelp-camp git.?

I tried these steps:

```
git add abc.js

git commit -m "inital commit"

git push
```

It is not working.

Comment: What is an exact error message you get?

Comment: `git push heroku master` should push the commits to your repo. 
If it fails, try to remove unnecessary remotes from the git.

Comment: error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jhardik366/yelp-camp.git'

Comment: @Ronnie, you probably meant `git push github master` for the "yelp-camp" repo, as opposed to "yelp-camp-19"

Comment: @glennjackman, Nope I meant heroku only. But now I'm not sure which 'existing repo' he is referring? If its a usual github repo, then yes you're right. It should be `git push github master`

Comment: @dynamo, where is your repo, on github or heroku?

Comment: My repo is on github

Comment: git push github master,
I tried this, but it showing this error

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jhardik366/yelp-camp.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart.

Comment: Maybe you should pull or fetch/rebase before push.

Comment: @SeddikOmar - How to do that?

Comment: Execute the following commands:

`git pull --rebase github master
git push -u github master`

(-u to set upstream next time when you want to push you will execute just git push without remote and branch )

Comment: @SeddikOmar Thanks, it worked!!